# Real analysis-Calculate the limit $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_0^2 \frac{nx^{\frac{n}{2}}}{(1+x^n)} dx$

Tags: real-analysis

$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_0^2 \frac{nx^{\frac{n}{2}}}{(1+x^n)} dx$

How to calculate the limit using the convergence theorem?
I have find the limit of $f_n(x)$, but it is a stepwise function and $f_n(x) \to \infty$ when $0<|x|\leq 1$ and $f_n(x) \to 0$ when $|x|>1$and$x=0$.

Comment: Are you sure about that last statement you make? For $x>1$, $f_n(x) \to_{n\to\infty} 0$.

Comment: For $x>1$, $f_n(x) \to \infty$, right?

Comment: No, for $x>1$ $f_n(x) \to_{n\to\infty} 0$, as I wrote. You have $f_n(x) \sim \frac{n x^{n/2}}{x^n} = nx^{-n/2}$.

Comment: You are right, I made a mistake. So how to find the dominating function of $f_n(x)$?

Comment: How to find the dominating function?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The change of variables $x=y^{1/n}$ shows the integral equals

$$\int_0^{2^n}\frac{y^{1/n}}{(1+y)\, y^{1/2}}\,dy.$$

You are now set up to use the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: Thank you! I have already solved it!

Answer (score 0):

The integral
\begin{align}
I_n&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^2\frac{nx^{n/2}}{1+x^n}dx=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^2\frac{2nx^ndx}{1+x^{2n}}\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^2\frac{2xdx^n}{1+x^{2n}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^22x\,d\arctan x^n.
\end{align}

In the limit $n\rightarrow\infty$, the function $\arctan x^n\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2}\Theta(x-1)$ approaches a step function. Therefore

$$\frac{d\arctan x^n}{dx}\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2}\delta(x-1)dx$$

approaches the Dirac delta function, and we have

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}I_n=\int_0^22x\,\frac{\pi}{2}\,\delta(x-1)dx=\pi.$$

Comment: Thank you! I have solved it by the hint from zhw' s answer.

Comment: I first tried saddle point approximation. I find that the peak does not approach Gaussian as the higher-order terms do not vanish in the $n\rightarrow\infty$ limit. Then I managed to do it with $\delta$ function.